# Paypal The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: php, paypal

I´m getting this response form a PayPal doExpressPayment request.

Can anyone point me where is the error on the request?

```
Array
(
    [errors] => Array(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-12-11T16:58:29Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 6fc8ed447aeb7
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 63.0
    [BUILD] => 4181146
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    )
)

[request] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=43.99
             &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=5.30
             &PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TAXAMT=2.46
             &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=51.75
             &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=0
             &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
             &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Six+Snowmen+at+Your+Hipline
             &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
             &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Six+Snowmen+at+Your+Hipline
             &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=43.99
             &VERSION=63.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
&PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TAXAMT=2.46
```

I think this is supposed to be:

```
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=2.46
```