# PayPal - currency is not supported

Tags: php, paypal, opencart, express-checkout

My client got this error the `totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts`. I am new to OpenCart & PayPal. I saw some other posts on StackOverflow

1. [Paypal The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825408/paypal-the-totals-of-the-cart-item-amounts-do-not-match-order-amounts)
2. [PayPal API: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512491/paypal-api-the-totals-of-the-cart-item-amounts-do-not-match-order-amounts)
3. http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=16699

I have tried that above OpenCart extension module

```
catalog/model/payment/pp_express.php
```

Changed line number 261

```
$item_total = number_format($item_total + $item_price, 2);
```

to

```
$item_total = number_format($item_total + $item_price, 2, '.', '');
```

Changed line number 180

```
$item_total += number_format($item_price * $item['quantity'], 2);
```

to

```
$item_total += number_format($item_price * $item['quantity'], 2, '.', '');
```

Changed line number 187

```
$data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE' . $i] = number_format($weight / $item['quantity'], 2);
```

to

```
$data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE' . $i] = number_format($weight / $item['quantity'], 2, '.', '');
```

Changed line number 267

```
$data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'] = number_format($item_total, 2);
```

to

```
$data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'] = number_format($item_total, 2, '.', '');
```

Changed line number 268

```
$data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = number_format($item_total, 2);
```

to

```
$data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = number_format($item_total, 2, '.', '');
```

Now, I get `Currency is not supported` error. How do I solve these paypal error?

```
Array
(
    [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
    [MAXAMT] => 99.92
    [RETURNURL] => http://www.domain.com/demo/index.php?route=payment/pp_express/checkoutReturn
    [CANCELURL] => http://www.domain.com/demo/index.php?route=checkout/checkout
    [REQCONFIRMSHIPPING] => 0
    [NOSHIPPING] => 1
    [LOCALECODE] => EN
    [LANDINGPAGE] => Login
    [HDRIMG] => 
    [HDRBORDERCOLOR] => 
    [HDRBACKCOLOR] => 
    [PAYFLOWCOLOR] => 
    [CHANNELTYPE] => Merchant
    [ALLOWNOTE] => 0
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => INR
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => 
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Blue Saree with White Embroidery Design
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => K7107
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 1480.00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMURL0] => http://www.domain.com/demo/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=112
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0] => 1.25
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTUNIT0] => kg
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0] => 12.00000000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHUNIT0] => in
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0] => 11.00000000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHUNIT0] => in
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0] => 10.00000000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTUNIT0] => in
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1] => shipping
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1] => Flat Shipping Rate
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1] => 3250.00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1] => 1
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 4730.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 4730.00
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a dump of the raw NVP request that is getting generated and sent to PayPal?

Comment: @AndrewAngell : I'm new to opencart & paypal. Can you tell me how do I get raw NVP request?

Answer (score 2):

Your currency code value is currently set to "INR" which is not a valid currency code for PayPal.  Check the [currency code docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/) for details about the currency codes that are available and valid.

Comment: I understand about that. How can I convert this INR to USD rupees in opencart?

Comment: Try https://openexchangerates.org/.  Looks like they provide an API for currency conversion.

Comment: Now INR support in PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

I would try passing the shipping amount like so:

`[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] =>3250.00`

The variable is unused in your example.

Comment: I have changed this -> $data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT'] = $this->currency->format($total_row['value'], false, false, false); Still, I got the same error currency is not supported

Comment: I don't see that currency code (INR) on the list of supported [Currency Codes](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/)

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142744/shipping-amount-calculation-error-in-opencart